# Finding Design patterns by Static Analysis of C# code by creating a Plugin for Resharper?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, resharper, static-code-analysis

I wanted to verify few design patterns in C# code by static analysis. I found that by creating a plugin for Resharper I can verify the patterns on-the-fly while i am coding. But I did not find good documentation related to its open APIs. Are there any links where I can find suitable documentation.

I Am using MVVM pattern so i want to verify that View-Model classes are not having any dependency 
with UI classes or elements (WPF elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/hadi_hariri/archive/2010/01/12/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-1-of-undefined.aspx) looks like it might help. There's a walkthrough for creating a context-aware plugin. It's continued [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-2-of-n/).

I reckon the second article is most relevant to you as it covers using the visitor pattern to hook into the ReSharper daemons - and perform some useful work.

[This page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/open_api.html) is the root of the Open API documentation.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the Reply..I had gone through these sites but found very little information about the Plugin Development. I wanted to know if there is some documentation like JavaDoc which helps to understand the APIs in a better way.

Comment: @Vinod - I don't think that there is anything like JavaDoc that describes the APIs themselves. All of the Open API documentation is pretty skeletal (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Plugin+Development). The 2.5x documentation is the most comprehensive - but it's mostly examples and nothing like javadoc. The later versions seem to just document the differences and new features between versions. Most of it seems to just refer to the PowerToy examples. I think the only way to learn it is to pick apart some of the examples.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper 5 introduced the Pattern Catalog AKA Structural Search and Replace. It allows you to create Quick Fixes and Context Actions easily without writing your own ReSharper plug-in. I would recommend checking it out to see if it will suffice for your needs before delving into writing a plug-in. You can find an overview here:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/

JetBrains also provides a sample catalog, which showcases some cool things that you can do, on their download page:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html

Comment: Thank You James for the reply.

I actually have many classes and namespaces. So i want to separate these into layers depending on the namespaces used in each class and restrict few layers from using few methods.

For example, I dont want have a dispose() method in view layer (I'm using MVVM design style).
So i need to know which class belongs to view layer first.
I can categorize the layers based on the namespaces used and the parent classes.
 Can we get the list of namespaces and parent classes (or interfaces) and then search for an expression in that class with "Search and replace"?

Comment: @Vinod - No, you would need a full-fledged ReSharper plug-in to do what you want to implement. With the Pattern Catalog, you can limit based on type (or derived), but not by namespace as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is currently somewhat fragmented. To get you started, take a look at the [ReSharper Extensibility Guide](http://nesteruk.org/blog/page/ReSharper-Extensibility-Guide.aspx) which I think targets version 4.5 but is still a good start. As the other poster mentioned, [Hadi Hariri's blog](http://hadihariri.com) is a good source for finding information on ReSharper plugin writing. Also, check out the [ReSharper PowerToys](http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com) for some sample code.

Finally, there are (very few, as yet) articles on ReSharper 6 plugin development available [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development). More content will be added soon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't go through the powerToy source much..Is there any document that could be useful in understanding the PowerToy source (A user friendly documentation) ..  ReSharper Extensibility Guide was really useful in understanding few basics.

I found some document relating to R# ([This link](http://www.rsdn.ru/projects/rsharp/article/rsharp_mag.xml#EGB) ), is this useful in Resharper Plugins?

Comment: @Vinod - no, this is relating to another project called R# that has nothing to do with ReSharper.

Comment: I love how on the ReSharper Extensibility Guide that you linked to, under the "Where to look for help" section it says "TODO"! Very much on-topic ;-)

Comment: Well you can get help on the JB forums, by asking a question here on SO, or even mailing me directly (dn/at/jetbrains/dot/com)